# Java - division of small number by big number

Tags: java, division

I have declared a variable as double. I wanted to  do division of two integer and  assign the output to that double variable.

But its not considering the values like 0.1 to 0.9. Only when the no is whole number like 4.0 its returning the answer

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
double itf=0;
a=4100;
b=6076  
itf=a/b;
System.out.println("itf:"+itf)
}
```

Output is itf: 0.0

Pls help..

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Int division: Why is the result of 1/3 == 0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685450/int-division-why-is-the-result-of-1-3-0)

Answer (score 7):

Most likely the variables `a` and `b` are defined as `int` , which will result in integer division result as 0 and when assigned to double it becomes 0.0. If you define `a`,`b` and `itf` as `double` then the result should be

```
0.6747860434496379
```

instead of

```
 0.0
```

Try this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    double itf = 0;
    double a = 4100;
    double b = 6076;
    itf = a / b;
    System.out.println("itf:" + itf);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`a` and `b` are both integers, so the result of `a/b` is also an integer, which is then cast to a double to be stored in `itf`. To get the correct result, you could either define `a` and `b` as doubles, or you could cast at least one of them to double. For instance:

```
itf = (double)a/b;
```

Answer (score 2):

Declare a or b as double.

**OR**
Cast the operation.

```
itf = (double)(a/b)
```

**OR** Cast one of the integers.

```
itf = ((double)a)/b
```

**OR** multiply with 1.0, which is double.

```
itf = (1.0*a)/b
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason for your result is that you are using integer division, then assign the result to a double value. This is your code unrolled:

```
int a = 4100;
int b = 6076;
int temp = a / b;
double itf = temp;
```

If you want to explicitly use floating point division, you need to tell the compiler that you do by casting at least one (or all to be sure) member of that operation to double or float. Example:

```
itf = (double)a / (double)b;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the foloving cast to at least one operand to `double`

```
itf=((double)a)/b;
```

or

```
itf=a/((double)b);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
double itf = ((double) a / (double) b);
```